# AWS China error validating stack policy Unknown resource type

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-secrets-manager

we have the following stack policy that we use to deploy on both aws and aws china.

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "Update:Replace",
        "Update:Delete"
      ],
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ResourceType": [
            "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
            "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
            "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "AWS::KMS::Key",
            "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret",
            "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
            "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient",
            "AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool",
            "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, the deployment fails only on the china enivronments with the following error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the SetStackPolicy
> operation: Error validating stack policy: Unknown resource type
> 'AWS::SecretsManager::Secret' in statement {}

Same thing happens if I remove the SecretsManager entry for Cognito:UserPool this time.

That leads me to believe that the builds will fail until I remove the stack policy all together from the cn environments.

Is there a list where it shows the supported resources for the stack policy in china, or maybe stack policies aren't supported in general?

I can't read Chinese so I can't understand the aws cn documentation.
Also keep in mind that the stack policy works without any problems in the normal aws builds.